# Generate Image from XAML Grid + Image via c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to generate an image for a tile consisting of a grid with background color and a PNG with transparent background.

```
var TestTile = new Grid()
                {
                    Background = colTemp,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                    Margin = new Thickness( 0, 12, 0, 0 ),
                };
                TestTile.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 366, 366));

                var ico = new Image() { 
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/mCloudSunT.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                };
                TestTile.Children.Add(ico);
...
bitmap.Render(TestTile, new TranslateTransform());
...
```

I get the image with background color but without the PNG. I get no error and the URI is correct (tested).

new code:

```
var colTemp = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 190, 206));
                var TestTile = new Grid()
                {                     
                    Background = colTemp,
                    Height = 336,
                    Width = 336,
                };                   

                var ico = new Image() {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/mCloudSunT.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                };
                Grid.SetColumn(ico, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(ico, 0);
                TestTile.Children.Add(ico);

                TestTile.Measure(new Size(336, 336));
                TestTile.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 366, 366));

                TestTile.UpdateLayout();
```

Here is the code for generating the image:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!store.DirectoryExists("shared/shellcontent"))
                    {
                        store.CreateDirectory("shared/shellcontent");
                    }  
                    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
                    bitmap.Render(TestTile, new TranslateTransform());
                    var stream = store.CreateFile("/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg");
                    bitmap.Invalidate();
                    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, 366, 336, 0, 100);
                    stream.Close();
```

And here the code for the use as tile background:

```
ShellTile PinnedTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
                FlipTileData UpdatedTileData = new FlipTileData
                {
                    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),                      
                };
                PinnedTile.Update(UpdatedTileData);
```

Comment: Is the image loaded correctly to ico? Can you verify?

Comment: Try adding Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions, not sure if they can be omitted

Comment: Try calling `TestTile.Arrange` after `TestTile.Children.Add(ico)`. You will most certainly also have to call `TestTile.Measure` before `Arrange`.

Comment: I have tried with Arrange after and before and with Measure - no chagings

Answer (score 0):

Call Measure and then Arrange after adding icon.

```
TestTile.Measure( new Size( 366,366 ) );
TestTile.Arrange( new Rect( 0, 0, 366, 366 ) );
TestTile.UpdateLayout();

...
WritableBitmap...
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for calling SetColumn, SetRow, Measure, Arrange, or UpdateLayout. Also, after calling Render(), call Invalidate(). Try this:

```
var colTemp = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 190, 206));
            var TestTile = new Grid()
            {                     
                Background = colTemp,
                Height = 336,
                Width = 336,
            };                   

            var ico = new Image() {
                Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/mCloudSunT.png", UriKind.Relative)),
            };

            TestTile.Children.Add(ico);

....

bitmap.Render(TestTile, new TranslateTransform());
bitmap.Invalidate();
```

Comment: no image - I have tried to add an other grid - it works but I have to use Arrange(). it works also with a textblock without Arrange() - but not with Image. It seams like it needed something like Arrange() but for images. I tried it also with an jpg instead a png no sucsess

Comment: Could you post the code showing the image implementation after it's created?